# How to add nth-item classes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, css-selectors

> http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/y7hBQ/

I'm making a simple jquery counting function that adds the following classes:

> 1. First & Last
> 2. Even & Odd
> 3. nth-item-# (counts in order)
> 4. nth-item--# (counts backwards)

I have the first two done pretty easily, but the second two are giving me trouble since I'm new to jQuery/Javascript

> You can see the jsfiddle here: 
>   http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/y7hBQ/

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.count, ul').each(function() {

        var countChildren = $(this).children();

        $(countChildren).filter(':even').addClass('even');
        $(countChildren).filter(':odd').addClass('odd');
        $(countChildren).first().addClass('first');
        $(countChildren).last().addClass('last');

        var numberOfChildren = $(countChildren).size();

        // $(countChildren).addClass('nth-item-' + #);
        //                                        ⬆
        //                           Fill with the elements number

        // $(countChildren).addClass('nth-item--' + #);
        //                                         ⬆
        //                   Fill with the elements number (negative count)
    });
});
```

I'm only focusing on the commented out lines

> Again here is the jsfiddle:
>   http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/y7hBQ/

Thanks ahead of time!

> **UPDATE :**
>
> I have two solutions below, I plan to use this on a very large scale so if you could recommend what would be the most efficient way it would help me a lot! Thanks!!

Comment: For your efficiency concerns check my answer. You have to get closer to native javascript for most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every effiency count then you should consider reduce iterations;

```
$('.count, ul').each(function() {
    var $children = $(this).children(),
        count = $children.size(),
        $item;
    $children.each(function(i) {
        $item = $(this)
            .addClass(i % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd')
            .addClass('nth-item-' + (i + 1))
            .addClass('nth-item--' + (count - i));
        if (i === 0) {
            $item.addClass('first');
        }
        if (i == count - 1) {
            $item.addClass('last');
        }
    });
});
```

This way you iterate on children only one time. When you use filters, it iterates and filters items according to your filter. [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/y7hBQ/30/).

A little benchmark is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/y7hBQ/33/).

Comment: Excellent work, I need to learn how to do that benchmark thing you did

Comment: Btw, I didn't want their to be a 0 on the nth-item count, I'll update your answer

Comment: I missed that. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7hBQ/27/)** for a **pure CSS** solution. It doesn't require any JavaScript (using the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3anth-child) selector).

---

Use the `.index()` method to get the index of the current element at a collection of elements. Also, since `.children()` returns a jQuery object, it's unnecessary to wrap `countChildren` in a `$`.

For clarification, the code below is using indexes starting at 1 and -1 (as hinted at your CSS code).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y7hBQ/18/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.count, ul').each(function() {

        var countChildren = $(this).children();

        countChildren.filter(':even').addClass('even');
        countChildren.filter(':odd').addClass('odd');
        countChildren.first().addClass('first');
        countChildren.last().addClass('last');

        var numberOfChildren = countChildren.size();

        countChildren.each(function(i){
            var posindex = countChildren.index(this) + 1,
                         //^ This can be replaced by i + 1, for efficiency
                negindex = numberOfChildren - posindex + 1;
            $(this).addClass('nth-item-' + posindex)
                   .addClass('nth-item--' + negindex);
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Could I get rid of the `numberOfChildren` variable by replacing the instance with `countChildren.size()` ?

Comment: That's inefficient. Since `.size()` always returns the same value at that point, it's better to cache the value. Imagine that your tree has a size of 2000 elements. That would result in 2000 additional function calls.

Comment: Is the answer below more efficient?

Comment: All of the current (3) answers are similar, except for inconsistent indexing. The answer from simshaun ends at index 0, while Ray's index starts at 0, and negatively ends at -1.

Comment: By "ends at index 0", I assume you mean e.g. "6-1"? See http://jsfiddle.net/y7hBQ/23/

Comment: @JamesKyle I have added the most efficient method to the top of my answer.

Comment: @RobW yeah I knew I could do that, I just wanted a cross browser way to do it

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.count, ul').each(function() {

        var countChildren = $(this).children();

        countChildren.filter(':even').addClass('even');
        countChildren.filter(':odd').addClass('odd');
        countChildren.first().addClass('first');
        countChildren.last().addClass('last');

        var numberOfChildren = countChildren.size();

        countChildren.each(function(i) {
            $(this).addClass('nth-item-'  + (i + 1) )
                   .addClass('nth-item--' + (numberOfChildren - i) );
        });
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7hBQ/23/)**

Comment: Is this more efficient than @Rob W 's answer above?

Comment: Both mine and his are practically the same, given his comment of `//^ This can be replaced by i + 1, for efficiency`. The call to `jQuery.index()` would cost a little, but is trivial.

Comment: Well I plan to use this on a very large scale so every efficiency counts

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
var count = countChildren.length;
countChildren.each(function(index) { 
    $(this).addClass('nth-item-'+index);
           .addClass('nth-item--'+(count-1-index));
});
```

There may be a faster way to do this, but.... hope this works for you.